# SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) Problema en C++

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo un árbol binario de búsqueda, el problema del titulo sucede cuando intento insertar un segundo elemento, en pocas palabras solo me deja insertar el primero.

Aquí esta el código involucrado:

```
void Arbol::insertar(Alumno a, Nodo *aux){
    Nodo *nuevo = new Nodo(a);
    Nodo *pos;
    if(!buscarCoincidencia(a,raiz)){
        if(raiz==nullptr){
            raiz=nuevo;
        }
        else{
            pos=buscarLugar(a,raiz);
            if(a.getMatricula()<pos->getAlumno().getMatricula()){
                pos->setIzq(nuevo);
            }
            else{
                pos->setDer(nuevo);
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        cout << "Elemento repetido, imposible introducir nuevamente." << endl;
    }
}

Nodo* Arbol::buscarLugar(Alumno a, Nodo *aux) {
    if(a.getMatricula()<aux->getAlumno().getMatricula()){
        if(aux->getIzq()== nullptr){
            return aux;
        }
        else {
            buscarLugar(a, aux->getIzq());
        }
    }
    else {
        if (aux->getDer() == nullptr) {
            return aux;
        } else {
            buscarLugar(a, aux->getIzq());
        }
    }
}

bool Arbol::buscarCoincidencia(Alumno a,Nodo *arbol) {
    if(arbol== nullptr){
        return false;
    }
    else if(arbol->getAlumno().getMatricula()==a.getMatricula()){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        buscarCoincidencia(a,arbol->getIzq());
        buscarCoincidencia(a,arbol->getDer());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu función `buscarLugar` no todas las rutas de ejecución devuelven un valor, eso provoca que al guardar el dato devuelto por una de esas rutas, éste sea un valor desconocido que al des-referenciarlo, provoca el error de acceso a memoria.

---

Cada vez que la función pasa por las líneas marcadas, no devuelves nada:

```
Nodo* Arbol::buscarLugar(Alumno a, Nodo *aux) {
    if (a.getMatricula() < aux->getAlumno().getMatricula()) {
        if (aux->getIzq() == nullptr) {
            return aux;
        }
        else {
            buscarLugar(a, aux->getIzq());
\\          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <--- No devuelve dato
        }
    }
    else {
        if (aux->getDer() == nullptr) {
            return aux;
        } else {
            buscarLugar(a, aux->getIzq());
\\          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <--- No devuelve dato
        }
    }
}
```

Al insertar, primero buscas dónde guardar el dato:

```
pos=buscarLugar(a,raiz);
```

Si la llamada a `buscarLugar` pasa por uno de los puntos en que no devuelves nada, `pos` tendrá un valor indeterminado que al des-referenciarlo falla:

```
if (a.getMatricula() < pos->getAlumno().getMatricula()){
//                        ~~ <-- Des-referencia
    pos->setIzq(nuevo);
//     ~~ <-- Des-referencia
}
else{
    pos->setDer(nuevo);
//     ~~ <-- Des-referencia
}
```

A falta de ver la implementación de `Nodo`, creo que tus punteros de izquierda y derecha no se inicializan a `nullptr` y tu código de `buscarLugar` sale por los puntos en que el retorno no queda inicializado.

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta:

Tu código tiene otros problemas que deberías revisar:

- El método `insertar` tiene fugas de memoria si el valor a insertar ya existe.
- El método `insertar` recibe un puntero a `Nodo` que no usa.
- La función `buscarCoincidencia` también finaliza sin devolver datos en un punto de su ejecución.

Comment: Muchas gracias, creo que aún tengo que mejorar demasiado!